# Creating Dynamic Facets in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to dynamically create facetts for a nested type that has dynamic attributes.

Suppose these articles are in my Index and that I'm searching for name and brand:

```
{
    name: iPhone 16GB
    brand: Apple
    type: Smartphone
    attributes: {
        Color: White

    }
}
{
    name: iPad
    brand: Apple
    type: Tablet
    attributes: {
        Color: Black
    }
}
{
    name: Cruzer USB 16GB
    brand: SanDisk
    type: USB-Stick
    attributes: {
        Color: Black
        Capacity: 16GB
        USB-Standard: USB 2.0
    }
}
{
    name: Cruzer USB 16GB
    brand: SanDisk
    type: USB-Stick
    attributes: {
        Color: Red
        Capacity: 16GB
        USB-Standard: USB 3.0
    }
}
```

Now, if I'm searching for 'Apple' I want to have a search result that has the following facets:

```
Brand:
    Apple 2
Type:
    Smartphone 1
    Tablet 1
Color:
    Black 1
    White 1
```

A search for '16GB' should include those facets:

```
Brand:
    Apple 1
    SanDisk 2
Type:
    Smartphone 1
    USB-Stick 2
Color:
    Black 1
    White 1
    Red 1
Capacity:
    16GB 2
USB-Standard: 
    USB 3.0 1
    USB 2.0 2
```

Likewise, every article can have arbitrary attributes.

The facetted search for brand and type is easy, but how could i do it for the attrubutes? Is this even possible with elasticsearch?

I hope you can unterstand what i mean...

Comment: One idea would be to get the mapping before doing a search and adding a facet for each attribute. But I don't think this is a good and efficient solution...

Comment: Another solution is to do a non-faceted search first. As soon as you get the search results, you do another search (by the ids of the result set). In this search you can create the facets by looking at the attributes of the results.
But this would include another Network roudtrip...
I'm still hoping someone has a real solution.

Comment: Why would flattening all attributes not be a valid solution?

Comment: I could do that, but the question how to dynamically add them as facets remains. To be sure, by flattening you mean for example { name: iPhone 16GB, brand: Apple, type: Smartphone, Color: Black }, do you?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. If I understand correctly, automatically making facets for all propertynames in `attributes` (by iterating over them) is not possible in ES afaik (not in Solr either). It may seem useful at first, but I doubt you won't be ending up having a list of attributenames on the clientside anyway (e.g: to sort which facets to show first, other presentational stuff, etc.) In that case that same list could be used to iterate the attributes. just my 2c.

Comment: The UI would look a lot like the example facets in my original question. So your point is that I should create the facets for the `attributes` on my own by grouping by the propertynames of all search results and counting the occurrences of the values?

Comment: @Felix , i have the same problem. Have you found a viable solution?

Comment: My current workaround is, that I include a list of the attribute keys in the document. Then I do a search with the user's query string with a terms aggregation/facet against the attribute keys. Now I have the attribute keys that match the given query. After that I issue another search request with the same query string but now with a term aggregation/facet for each attribute key.

I know it is kind of hacky and requires multiple requests. I didn't really had time to think about the problem again now that we have aggregations. Maybe you could nest aggr. to do the same thing in only one request.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "Apple"
      }
   },
   "facets": {
      "tags": {
         "terms": {
            "fields": ["name","brand","type","attributes.Color"]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't know in advance which attributes the articles that match the query have.

Comment: It will check in every attribute the articles

Comment: How? In your query, you have only specified the color attribute ("attributes.Color").